# click & drag to create a div with its own size

Tags: html, jquery

I'd like to know if you have any idea on how I could click and drag on a canva to create a div.
Like in a video-game where you drag & drop to create an area.

Is there any plugin or things that were made in order to achieve that?

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on Ludwig's snippet ... this will draw some squares on the page using mousedown and mouseup event listeners :)

EDIT: Had too much fun playing with this so here is an updated version with a select box to help you draw the selection, and now working in all directions :) I'd still recommend using a library like this one (https://github.com/Simonwep/selection) though, especially if you want touchscreen support.

```js
// declare some global variables
let showSelection = false;
let Xstart;
let Ystart;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).mousedown(function(event){
        // set a variable that indicates the user is drawing a selection
        showSelection=true;

        // save the position where the mouse click started
        Xstart=event.pageX;
        Ystart=event.pageY;

        // create the select box element and give it some starting positions
        $('<div id="selection"></div>')
            .css({
                "left": Xstart + 'px',
                "top": Ystart + 'px',
            })
        .appendTo(document.body);
    });

    $(document).mousemove(function(event){
        
        // if we are making a selection lets keep updating our select box dimensions
        if(showSelection == true) {
            
            // horizontal selection
            if (event.pageX > Xstart) {
                // left to right
                $('#selection').css({
                    "width": event.pageX-Xstart + 'px'
                })
            } else {
                // right to left
                $('#selection').css({
                    "left": event.pageX,
                    "width": Xstart-event.pageX + 'px'
                })
            }

            // vertical selection
            if (event.pageY > Ystart) {
                // top to bottom
                $('#selection').css({
                    "height": event.pageY-Ystart + 'px'
                })
            } else {
                // bottom to top
                $('#selection').css({
                    "top": event.pageY,
                    "height": Ystart-event.pageY + 'px'
                })
            }
        }

    });

    $(document).mouseup(function(event){

        // we can borrow the needed values from the #selection element to draw our 'area' :)
        LeftVal = $("#selection").css('left')
        TopVal = $("#selection").css('top')
        WidthVal = $("#selection").css('width')
        HeightVal = $("#selection").css('height')

        // create the area element and give it the dimensions
        $('<div class="area"></div>')
            .css({
                "left": LeftVal,
                "top": TopVal,
                "width": WidthVal,
                "height": HeightVal
            })
            .appendTo(document.body);
        
        // get rid of the selection element from the DOM
        $( "#selection" ).remove();
        // and set our showSelection variable back to false
        showSelection=false;

    });
});
```

```css
.area {
    position: absolute;
    background-color:lightgray;
}

#selection {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that's working so fine!
my concern now is to be able to see what I draw, that's another issue nonetheless :)
thanks a lot James. :)

Comment: hehe, I thought that might be the next step .. I'm giving that ago atm. I also foresee the problem if someone tries to draw right to left, the current code won't work ;D

Comment: yeah! that's the issue I was facing with other techniques!
Thanks again :)

Comment: no worries :) always fun playing around with a bit of DOM manipulation. But to answer the other part of your question ... there is a lot of libraries that do this sort of thing. And because of all the complexities you will run into, as we have just mentioned, let alone if you want it to be mobile/touch compatible. It's worth using them. I just found this one ... I've never used it but it looks pretty ideal for your use https://github.com/Simonwep/selection

Comment: I didn't noticed you updated the post!
thanks a lot for the awesome work!

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:
https://simonwep.github.io/selection/

In combination with something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click(function(event){
        $('<div id="kenobi">Hello there</div>')
            .css({
                "left": event.pageX + 'px',
                "top": event.pageY + 'px'
            })
      .appendTo(document.body);
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    position: relative;
}

#kenobi {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```